# GetExitCodeProcess() return 1 when process is not yet finished

Tags: c, windows, api

If I create a process and two pipe sets for it, and that process needs at a certain time some user input, the `GetExitCodeProcess()` from the Windows C API returns always `1`. As an example you can take the Windows `time` command, this will return:

```
The current time is: ...
Enter the new time:
```

And then exits immediately without waiting for input.

I don't want the process to finish until the it has really finished so I can pipe input to it. How can I solve this issue.

I have built this loop (I still want to be able to determine when to process has finished):

```
for (;;)
{
    /* Pipe input and output */
    if (GetExitCodeProcess(...) != STILL_ACTIVE) break;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to know when the process has finished, don't use GetExitCodeProcess - consider what would happen if the process exit code is STILL_ACTIVE!  Instead, use WaitForSingleObject.  The process handle will be signaled once the process has exited.

Comment: Yes, but WaitForSingleObject locks your current thread. Also Microsoft advises not to use STILL_ACTIVE as exit code (259).

Comment: If you're expecting window messages, use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects instead of WaitForSingleObject.  If you really need to poll, however, you can use WaitForSingleObject with a timeout of zero.  This tests the state of the object and returns immediately.  Microsoft may recommend against an exit code of STILL_ACTIVE, but few if any programmers take any precautions against it.  Since it's just as easy to do it the right way, why take the risk?

Comment: You are right, I'll change it. Thanks for your helpful comment!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`GetExitCodeProcess` doesn't *return* `STILL_ACTIVE`; `STILL_ACTIVE` is the exit code returned via the `lpExitCode` out parameter.  You need to test the exit code that was returned:

```
DWORD exitCode = 0;
if (GetExitCodeProcess(handle, &exitCode) == FALSE)
{
    // Handle GetExitCodeProcess failure
}

if (exitCode != STILL_ACTIVE)
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant:  Agreed!  Answer amended.  (I had skimmed over the declaration and just read "returns nonzero" in the Returns documentation...)

Comment: Of course. Stupid of me. This bug was there for a long time but I only noticed it when I tried to pipe input to a program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does not work for me, the exit code of the process is 0 even if the process is waiting for a message box and the return value is 1.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, I tested your code and while the process is still running I get ExitCode = 0.