# GetExitCodeProcess return 1

Tags: vbscript, mfc

I have a MFC application which uses CreateProcess and then, call GetExitCodeProcess to get the exit code. But GetExitCodeProcess returns 1 and it fail.

More detail about my application -

My application run two process first is bat file and after successful completion of first process I create second process which is vb script. Both run in automation environment. This script contains simply a message box.

My second process fail with error 1 return by GetExitCodeProcess().

When I run scripts in reverse order like first as vbscript and second as bat file, both executes successfully.

I am not able to understand why my VB script fail with error code 1?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Jyoti

Comment: The problem is on line 63 of your VB script ...... probably.

Comment: Show us your script.

Comment: My VB Script contains code -->                                       'vbscript
msgbox "test"                                                             But I have verified by running script in automation environment. it is working fine. But when I run it via my application, it returns error 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetExitCodeProcess() return 1 when process is not yet finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725958/getexitcodeprocess-return-1-when-process-is-not-yet-finished)

Answer (score 0):

As said in [GetExitCodeProcess() return 1 when process is not yet finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725958/getexitcodeprocess-return-1-when-process-is-not-yet-finished) `GetExitCodeProcess` returns a `BOOL` to signal success or failure. The process return code is returned in the second parameter to `GetExitCodeProcess`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for looking at my query and trying to answer it. 
I have resolved this issue, hence thought to share solution.

In my application I was executing vb script with 'cscript' as command line parameter.
When I changed that parameter to 'wscript', it prompt me message that the filename.vbs not exists.

Then I understand the process is executing but it does not get vb script file and hence the Process fail with GetExitCodeProcess as return value = 1

This problem was not understood because I was using cscript. Whereas, 
'cscript' runs entirely in the command line and is ideal for non-interactive scripts.
And 'wscript' will popup Windows dialogue boxes for user interaction.
Hence when I use wscript I understood the root cause.

The solution for this issue is I have checked the vbscript file exists or not. It will go ahead only if the file exists, till that, application wait for creation of vbscript file.